# What is a North-America™ word?

Tags: pattern, language, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **North-America™** word.
Here is a list of North-America™ and not North-America™ words:

[image: North-America™ word listing]

And CSV version:

```
North-America™ Word,Not a North-America™ Word
Colonial,Explorer
Debate,Argue
Imperial,Island
Judicial,Judge
Popular,Ordinary
Superficial,Fake
Universal,Earth
Singular,Country
Vulnerable,Sick
```

**QUESTION:** What is the rule to tell whether a word is a **North-America™** word or not?

**edit:** Added the [Language] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

North-America words are

> english (american) and also spanish (mexican)

**OP edit:**

> More specifically they are exact English-Spanish Cognates

Comment: This looks to be correct, although the question then seriously overlooks rot13(Serapu) in all this....

Comment: This is correct!  These words are rot13(rknpg Ratyvfu-Fcnavfu Pbtangrf).

Comment: @El-Guest I thought about that.  rot13(Ubjrire, bayl nebhaq <3% bs gur cbchyngvba va AN fcrnx Serapu.)  I had to cut it off somewhere.

Comment: Haha @KyleWilliamson no worries — I’m Canadian which is why I noticed right away!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data available, one of the option for the rule can be as follows:

> North American word has a minimum of 3 vowels. If the NA word starts with a vowel, there should be 3 more vowels. If this condition is not satisfied, it is Not a NA word.

Words that meet the North American word rule:

> Colonial    - 3 vowels
>
>  Debate      - 3 vowels
>
>  Imperial    - 3 vowels excluding the first I
>
>  Judicial    - 3 vowels
>
>  Popular     - 3 vowels
>
>  Superficial - 3 vowels
>
>  Universal   - 3 vowels excluding the first U
>
>  Singular    - 3 vowels
>
>  Vulnerable  - 3 vowels

Words that DO NOT meet the North American word rule

> Explorer    - has only 2 vowels excluding the first E
>
>  Argue       - has only 2 vowels excluding the first A
>
>  Island      - has only 1 vowel excluding the first I
>
>  Judge       - has only 2 vowels
>
>  Ordinary    - has only 2 vowels excluding the first O
>
>  Fake        - has only 2 vowels
>
>  Earth       - has only 1 vowel  excluding the first E
>
>  Country     - has only 2 vowels
>
>  Sick        - has only 1 vowel

Comment: I think this rule is too complex. It also does not explain the title

Comment: This is incorrect.  I added the "Language" tag, which I should've had at the beginning. I'm fairly new to Puzzling and didn't realize that tag existed.

Comment: But by adding that tag it should work as a clue.